# What's regular blocking arrangement ? (GDAL)

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal

I am using GDAL tools to retrieve PostGiS raster. The code(command line) I am using is as follows :

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid "PG:host=localhost dbname='database' user='postgres' password='admin' schema='public' table='rastertable' where='rid=2'" postgis.asc
```

And it shows error:  rastertable doesn't seem to have regular blocking arrangement. Only tables with regular blocking arrangement can be read from now.

I never heard the blocking arrangement before and I am sure the table in my postgis is a raster table. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Until this question showed up, the top Google hit for the error message text was at http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/frmts_wtkraster.html. Section 3.2 looks like the relevant one (although its answer may be unsatisfactory: "the driver is under development, and will work with more raster arrangements ASAP").

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of the GDAL PostIS Raster driver. I think that message comes from a really old version of GDAL. I think 1.7, or 1.8.

The message means that PostGIS Raster doesn't consider your loaded raster image as *regularly blocked* image. Let me clarify that:

A PostGIS Raster table is, basically, a bunch of raster tiles, stored in a PostgreSQL table, coming from a raster file from disk.

To load a raster file into PostgreSQL with PostGIS 2.0 extension, you need to use the [PostGIS Raster loader](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Raster_Loader). One of the most interesting loader's options is -t flag. It forces the loader to split your image into tiles. So, each resulting tile (plus its metadata) will be a PostgreSQL row. With this method, **all the tiles have the same dimensions** (width and height), and you can say the resulting PostGIS Raster table has **regular blocking**.

However, PostGIS Raster extension allows more raster arrangements. The above is the easiest case. The point is not all tiles stored in a PostGIS Raster table are forced to have the same dimensions. Neither the same pixel size. So, at the end, your PostGIS Raster table may be a bunch of unrelated tiles, with totally different dimensions.

The old versions of GDAL PostGIS Raster driver just were able to work with the first easier arrangement: raster with same size tiles. Even raster images without tiles (I mean, all the image in just one row) were considered as non-regularly blocked images. And the reading speed was really low, anyway.

The current version of the driver (packed with GDAL 1.10) is much faster, and allows irregularly blocked images. Could you please give it a try? And don't hesitate to ask me if you have more problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it later. How can contact you directly? Of course in your convenience.

Comment: Your welcome. Just drop me an email: jorgearevalo at libregis.org

Comment: Hi Jorge, I sent you an email.

Comment: Hi Jorge， I drop you another email. Do you check that email address frequently ?

Comment: Yes. I check it every day. I'll answer you before Monday.